# Amazon MWS Api usage

Tags: node.js, amazon-mws

I am using "http://www.amazon.de/dp/{ASIN}" to get product info.
But after getting response it doesn't return product "SellerSKU"

Is there any way that I can get "SellerSKU" of a product specified by "ASIN"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had same situation.
And I found that there is only some limited way to get it.

https://mws.amazonservices.com/FulfillmentInventory/2010-10-01?Action=ListInventorySupply

ListInventorySupply api of Fulfillment Inventory lists returns information about the availability of a seller's inventory.

Request parameter includes SellerSKUs, QueryStartDateTime, MarketplaceId, ResponseGroup

Here you can omit SellerSKUs, and you can pass QueryStartDateTime.

Then you will get InventorySupplyList including SellerSKU and ASIN matches.
You should find the product's SellerSKU in this list.

But the problem is that it returns only available inventory list.
It will not work when product you are finding is not in available inventory list.

In this case you should make the user manually add SellerSKU in your application.

For more information, please take a look at http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inventory/FBAInventory_ListInventorySupply.html

Hope this would help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is very helpful to me.